# Find if a version number is in a specified range

Tags: php

I have a version number as a string, the version number can have major version as well as up to 3 minor version positions.
E.g. `3.4.0.1`

I need to find out if this version is within a predefined version range:
E.g `3.1.0 - 3.3.5.1`

I can parse the versions to 4 integers and do a comparison then but I'm sure there is a much more elegant solution for that.

Thanks

#### Update

I guess it can be simplified further if assuming that the version range has only one minor version position, E.g `3.0 - 3.4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [version_compare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php):

```
$version = "3.4.0.1";
if (version_compare($version, "3.1.0", ">=") && version_compare($version, "3.3.5.1", "<=")) {
//Version in range
}
```

Comment: Isn't version_compare used only to compare PHP versions? That's what I understand from the [PHP manual](http://it2.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)

Comment: @LeaCohen Yes, but this is a pretty cool "hack". The docs state that it'll work as long as you use version numbering like PHP does.

Comment: Works perfectly.... So glad i asked this question and not implemented the brute force method... seems like PHP does have a function for everything...